# How to static_assert if a constexpr number is in a constexpr array at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, static-assert

I want to check if a constexpr number is in a constexpr array at compile time. If not, stop compiling. My ideographic example:

```
constexpr void PinValid(uint8_t Pin)
{
    constexpr uint8_t ValidPins[] = {2, 3, 18, 19, 20, 21};
    for (uint8_t P : ValidPins)
        if (Pin == P)
            return;
    static_assert(false);
}
```

This code fails for any given Pin even if it is in the ValidPins.

Comment: ``static_assert(false)`` will always fail at compile time.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn So how to do this check?

Answer (score 3):

You can write like this:

```
constexpr bool PinValid(uint8_t Pin)
{
    constexpr uint8_t ValidPins[] = {2, 3, 18, 19, 20, 21};
    for (uint8_t P : ValidPins)
        if (Pin == P)
            return true;
    return false;
}

static_assert(PinValid(3));
```

Comment: Cool. I thought constexpr functions cannot have more than one returns. But your code did passed compilation. So what is it that is limited to have only one return statement?

Comment: I think 'constexpr'  means the func returns a same result for a same input. It can have various results. [constexpr specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add the following solution, even if the quality of the error message isn't as good as in the example in the other answer, on some compilers.

In c++20 you can throw an exception in a constexpr function which will result in a compilation error if it gets thrown at compile-time:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>


consteval void PinValid(uint8_t Pin)
{
    constexpr uint8_t ValidPins[] = {2, 3, 18, 19, 20, 21};
    for (uint8_t P : ValidPins)
        if (Pin == P)
            return;
    throw std::invalid_argument("not a valid pin");
}

int main() {
    PinValid(20);
    PinValid(5); // Does not compile
}
```

See the example on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KP1K7oPac). Notice that it currently doesn't work on clang, though

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my compiler has not implemented C++20 yet, as indicated in the question's tags.